# Uninstalling civivolunteer - trigger remains

Tags: extension, civivolunteer, trigger

I uninstalled civivolunteer. We've opted to instead use an activity type with a couple custom fields tracking role and time spent. Anyway, when uninstalling it did not delete the 2 volunteer and volunteer commendation activity type data but does delete the volunteer custom field data :/

So, we restored the tables:

- civicrm_custom_group
- civicrm_custom_field
- civicrm_option_value
- civicrm_uf_field
- civicrm_uf_group
- civicrm_uf_join

and manually cleaned up what civilvolunteer adds. However, a trigger remains. Each time we upgrade extensions a civivolunteer trigger is trying to run, see error below when upgrading another extension)

Key line:

*#2 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php(997): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such table", -18, 16, (Array:2), "CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_value_civivolunteer_20_after_insert after insert ON ci...")*

```
Aug 25 09:46:49  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(942): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php(997): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such table", -18, 16, (Array:2), "CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_value_civivolunteer_20_after_insert after insert ON ci...")
#3 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-18, 16, (Array:2), "CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_value_civivolunteer_20_after_insert after insert ON ci...")
#4 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -18, 16, (Array:2), "CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_value_civivolunteer_20_after_insert after insert ON ci...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php(1928): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php(936): DB_common->raiseError(-18, NULL, NULL, "CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_value_civivolunteer_20_after_insert after insert ON ci...", "1146 ** Table 'example_civicrm.civicrm_value_civivolunteer_20' doesn't exist")
#7 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php(406): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php(1234): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_value_civivolunteer_20_after_insert after insert ON ci...")
#9 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2696): DB_common->query("CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_value_civivolunteer_20_after_insert after insert ON ci...")
#10 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1829): DB_DataObject->_query("CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_value_civivolunteer_20_after_insert after insert ON ci...")
#11 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(454): DB_DataObject->query("CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_value_civivolunteer_20_after_insert after insert ON ci...")
#12 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1565): CRM_Core_DAO->query("CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_value_civivolunteer_20_after_insert after insert ON ci...", FALSE)
#13 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/SqlTriggers.php(209): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_value_civivolunteer_20_after_insert after insert ON ci...", (Array:0), TRUE, NULL, FALSE, FALSE)
#14 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/SqlTriggers.php(155): Civi\Core\SqlTriggers->enqueueQuery("CREATE TRIGGER civicrm_value_civivolunteer_20_after_insert after insert ON ci...")
#15 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/SqlTriggers.php(54): Civi\Core\SqlTriggers->createTriggers((Array:19), NULL)
#16 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(2335): Civi\Core\SqlTriggers->rebuild(NULL, FALSE)
#17 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(395): CRM_Core_DAO::triggerRebuild()
#18 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Manager.php(228): CRM_Core_Invoke::rebuildMenuAndCaches(TRUE)
#19 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Downloader.php(126): CRM_Extension_Manager->replace("/tmp/tmp-SHLdHt//stripe-6.6.1")
#20 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/Extension.php(239): CRM_Extension_Downloader->download("com.drastikbydesign.stripe", "https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/archive/6.6.1/stripe-6.6.1.zip")
#21 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_extension_download((Array:4))
#22 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(149): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:8))
#23 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(81): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:8))
#24 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(22): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("Extension", "download", (Array:2))
#25 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php(190): civicrm_api("Extension", "download", (Array:2))
#26 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(513): CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions->postProcess()
#27 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(144): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#28 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(43): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next", "Next")
#29 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next")
#30 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next")
#31 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(347): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#32 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(395): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#33 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(140): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->edit(2, NULL)
#34 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php(105): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
#35 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions->run((Array:3), NULL)
#36 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#37 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#38 /var/www/example/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1172): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#39 /var/www/example/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(292): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#40 /var/www/example/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(316): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#41 /var/www/example/wp-includes/plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#42 /var/www/example/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#43 {main}
```

I've tried to run the rebuild database triggers and it did not resolve. Without re-installing and uninstalling and going thru that nightmare again how can we remove this trigger?

Comment: If you `select * from civicrm_managed` is there still something stuck in there for civivolunteer?

Comment: Not seeing anything there. We think it is safe to remove from 'civicrm_custom_group' 'CiviVolunteer' which has a table_name of 'civicrm_value_civivolunteer_20' which no longer exists and for which the trigger is trying to reference.

Comment: Yes that makes sense to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the following tables from from 'civicrm_custom_group' table and everything is working as expected:

- civicrm_value_civivolunteer_...
- civicrm_value_volunteer_com_...

This was the only remaining civivolunteer trigger reference that we found.